# Swagger Schema: oneOf, anyOf, allOf valid at the same time?

Tags: schema, swagger

I'm just reading through the more advanced validators in the `Schema` definition of the Swagger specification:

```
{
   "Schema":{
      "type":"object",
      "properties":{
         "title":{
            "type":"string"
         },
         "multipleOf":{
            "type":"number",
            "minimum":0,
            "exclusiveMinimum":true
         },
         "maximum":{
            "type":"number"
         },
         "exclusiveMaximum":{
            "type":"boolean",
            "default":false
         },
         "minimum":{
            "type":"number"
         },
         "exclusiveMinimum":{
            "type":"boolean",
            "default":false
         },
         "maxLength":{
            "type":"integer",
            "minimum":0
         },
         "minLength":{
            "type":"integer",
            "minimum":0,
            "default":0
         },
         "pattern":{
            "type":"string",
            "format":"regex"
         },
         "maxItems":{
            "type":"integer",
            "minimum":0
         },
         "minItems":{
            "type":"integer",
            "minimum":0,
            "default":0
         },
         "uniqueItems":{
            "type":"boolean",
            "default":false
         },
         "maxProperties":{
            "type":"integer",
            "minimum":0
         },
         "minProperties":{
            "type":"integer",
            "minimum":0,
            "default":0
         },
         "required":{
            "type":"array",
            "items":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "minItems":1,
            "uniqueItems":true
         },
         "enum":{
            "type":"array",
            "items":{

            },
            "minItems":1,
            "uniqueItems":true
         },
         "type":{
            "type":"string",
            "enum":[
               "array",
               "boolean",
               "integer",
               "number",
               "object",
               "string"
            ]
         },
         "not":{
            "oneOf":[
               {
                  "$ref":"#/definitions/Schema"
               },
               {
                  "$ref":"#/definitions/Reference"
               }
            ]
         },
         "allOf":{
            "type":"array",
            "items":{
               "oneOf":[
                  {
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/Schema"
                  },
                  {
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/Reference"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "oneOf":{
            "type":"array",
            "items":{
               "oneOf":[
                  {
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/Schema"
                  },
                  {
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/Reference"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "anyOf":{
            "type":"array",
            "items":{
               "oneOf":[
                  {
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/Schema"
                  },
                  {
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/Reference"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "items":{
            "oneOf":[
               {
                  "$ref":"#/definitions/Schema"
               },
               {
                  "$ref":"#/definitions/Reference"
               }
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "type":"object",
            "additionalProperties":{
               "oneOf":[
                  {
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/Schema"
                  },
                  {
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/Reference"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "additionalProperties":{
            "oneOf":[
               {
                  "$ref":"#/definitions/Schema"
               },
               {
                  "$ref":"#/definitions/Reference"
               },
               {
                  "type":"boolean"
               }
            ],
            "default":true
         },
         "description":{
            "type":"string"
         },
         "format":{
            "type":"string"
         },
         "default":{

         },
         "nullable":{
            "type":"boolean",
            "default":false
         },
         "discriminator":{
            "$ref":"#/definitions/Discriminator"
         },
         "readOnly":{
            "type":"boolean",
            "default":false
         },
         "writeOnly":{
            "type":"boolean",
            "default":false
         },
         "example":{

         },
         "externalDocs":{
            "$ref":"#/definitions/ExternalDocumentation"
         },
         "deprecated":{
            "type":"boolean",
            "default":false
         },
         "xml":{
            "$ref":"#/definitions/XML"
         }
      },
      "patternProperties":{
         "^x-":{

         }
      },
      "additionalProperties":false
   }
}
```

The thing that I am thinking about is combinations of the anyOf, allOf, oneOf and not keywords. I have two questions.

The first question is: "can they be used in conjunction"? Like so:

```
{
   "allOf" : [
      {
         "minItems" : 0
      },
      {
         "maxItems" : 10
      }
   ],
   "anyOf" : [
      {
         "type" : "array",
         "items" : {
            "type" : "string"
         }
      },
      {
         "type" : "array",
         "items" : {
            "type" : "integer"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This example is, of course, needlessly complicated. But is it valid? Or can you only use one modifier but not the others?

The second question is, can anybody point me to a real-world example where one of these operators have been used in conjunction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The thing that I am thinking about is combinations of the anyOf, allOf, oneOf and not keywords. I have two questions.
>
> The first question is: "can they be used in conjunction"?

Yes, `allOf`, `anyOf`, `oneOf` and `not` can be used in conjunction. OpenAPI Specification follows the rules of JSON Schema here, and in JSON Schema adjacent keywords work as branches of an implicit `allOf` ([source](https://github.com/cloudflare/doca/issues/52)). So your example is equivalent to:

```
{
  "allOf": [
    {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "minItems": 0
        },
        {
          "maxItems": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

That said, this example is too complex and can be simplified into:

```
{
  "minItems": 0,
  "maxItems": 10,
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "oneOf": [
      {
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```