# Building an OpenAPI response, including oneOf, and maybe allOf

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I am trying to build up a response from a variety of schema components using OpenAPI 3. There are basically three parts to the response:

1. A shared component that other endpoints use (i.e. success/failure flags). - `#/components/schemas/core_response_schema` inside `allOf`.
2. Properties that *all* responses on this endpoint use (i.e., `user_id`) - the `properties` component of the below.
3. One of several schemas that will vary depending on the type of user. - the `oneOf` component.

I've determined that I have to use `allOf` to be able to mix properties (item 2) and the core response (item 1), though this feels wrong as there's only one item. I tried a `$ref`, but it didn't work.

The below successfully passes three different OpenAPI linting tools, but in the example it builds, Swagger UI does not show the item 2 things (properties), and *does* show all of the item 3 things (should be oneOf).

```
"responses": {
    "200": {
        "description": "Operation successfully executed.",
        "content": {
            "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                    "properties": {
                        "user_id": {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/user_id"
                        },
                        "results": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/result_user_by_id"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object",
                    "allOf": [
                        {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/core_response_schema"
                        }
                    ],
                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/user_type_a"
                        },
                        {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/user_type_b"
                        },
                        {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/user_type_c"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"components": {
    "schemas": {
        "core_response_schema": {
            "properties": {
                "success": {
                    "description": "A flag indicating whether the request was successfully completed or not.",
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "num_results": {
                    "description": "The number of results for this request",
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "user_id": {
            "description": "Unique 10 character `user_id`.",
            "type": "string",
            "maxLength": 10,
            "minLength": 10,
            "example": "a1b2c3d4e5"
        },
    }
}
```

And example payloads for two users. Type A and B (it's a contrived example).

User Type A:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "num_results": 1,
    "user_id": "c1b00cb714",
    "results": [{
            "user_type": "a",
            "group_id": "e7a99e3769",
            "name": null,
            "title": null,
            ... (and so on until we get to the stuff that's unique to this type of user) ...
            "favourite_artworks": [
                "sunflowers",
                "landscapes"
            ],
            "artwork_urls": [
                "http://sunflowers.example"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

User Type B:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "num_results": 1,
    "user_id": "c1b00cb715",
    "results": [{
            "user_type": "B",
            "group_id": "e7a99e3769",
            "name": null,
            "title": null,
            ... (and so on until we get to the stuff that's unique to this type of user) ...
            "supported_charities": [
                "UN Foundations"
            ],
            "charity_urls": [
                "http://www.un.int"
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

What's the correct way to merge together different schemas and properties in OpenAPI? Is this right and Swagger UI just can't handle it?

And how do you mix a schema with properties without having to use `allOf`?

This suggests it's possible: [Swagger Schema: oneOf, anyOf, allOf valid at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49604468/swagger-schema-oneof-anyof-allof-valid-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Can you also post the `user_id` schema and add some JSON payload examples with `user_type_a`/`user_type_b`/`user_type_c` parts that vary based on the `user_id`? Such scenario would probably be best handled using model inheritance and `discriminator` rather than `oneOf`, but it help to see payload examples to be sure.

Comment: @Helen - thanks for the feedback. I've added the schemas and a couple of payload examples. Please note that it's a contrived, simplified example of my actual schema, but the principle is the same.

Comment: @Helen I did come across the `discriminator` element but it didn't quite seem to suit this. But maybe that's just because I didn't quite grok it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation, I've determined this is a bug in swagger-ui - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3803 - they simply don't support `oneOf` (or `anyOf`) currently.

As far as at least three different linting tools are concerned, a mixture of `anyOf`, `oneOf`, and `allOf` can be used together in the same schema.

Redoc appears to have similar problems - https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc/issues/641

Comment: I am the ghost of Christmas Future.  Things have gotten ... well, they haven't gotten better, that's for sure.